# in Rails my Cropper is being displayed wrong and will only display with a manual page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am on rails -v 5.1 and trying to display an image cropper on my site.
I am using the paperclip gem to handle image uploading, and once the image is saved to the model you are then redirected to the cropper. At this point, everything is displaying fine but I am running into an issue during the edit where the user can choose to re-crop the photo. when you follow the recrop link the cropper is being displayed prior to the width being rendered through js and causing no part of the cropper to function unless you manually refresh the page. I am pretty sure this issue has to do with turbolinks causing the JavaScript to render prior to a dom.ready function which is not included in the stock cropper.js file. My question is how can I monkey patch this to delay the display until the dom is ready? Or am I missing something and there is a different approach that I can take?

-/app/views/crop.html.haml

```
= form_for @photo_post do |f|
  = f.cropbox :image, width: 300
  = f.crop_preview :image
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

-/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def crop
  render 'crop'
end
```

-/config/routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'crop'
  end
end
```

I have been searching the for this solution for hours now, I feel like I am making this way harder then it should be, I just can't seem to figure out where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cropper is JS 
I needed to call

```
document.on('turbolinks:load', fucntion(){
   someCropperFunction
});
```